# Weekly Featured Image: Nov 14, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 14 November** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Nov 13th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/weekly-featured-image-nov-7-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Voting closes on **November 136th**? Might want to fix that ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Lonely and Cold

[image: Lonely and cold]
[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/3057122)

Comment: this is *cool!*

Comment: thanks @studiohack.

Comment: Love the crisp subject vs. bokeh :)

Comment: Thanks @jaxxon. A great honor indeed coming from the master of colour and macro himself.

Comment: This is a winner, for sure! Glad we'll get to see it for a week :)

Answer (score 18):

**Tso Moriri**

[image: Tso Moriri (Moriri Lake), Ladakh]

[Tso Moriri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsomoriri_Wetland_Conservation_Reserve) ('Tso' means Lake in Ladakhi) is one of the highest lakes [4,595 m (15,075 ft)]. A nice, calm and freaking cold place.

It will be great if someone can crack the mystry behind the blue stripes. It is a sunset and sun was setting behind my back.

**[Large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6323251894/in/photostream/lightbox/)**

Comment: This s really beautiful!!! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks Dulini .

Comment: +1 Really like these full colours that makes the ordinary view an extraordinary

Comment: Thanks @peter_budo.

Comment: This was great.. I hope you submit it again!

Comment: Thanks @jaxxon. Submitted again.

Answer (score 12):

### V

[image: V]

This was taken on an Occupy London StockExchange march to the Houses of Parliament in London. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6317579855/).

Answer (score 10):

**Butterfly**

[image]

[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/68837326@N06/6325204689/)

Answer (score 7):

### Lock'n'Key

[image]

[Larger Version](http://500px.com/photo/3095102)

Answer (score 3):

**Hannah**

[image: Hannah]

A picture of my niece-in-law I took sort of accidentally while I was playing with a new toy (SB-700 flash). I'm not familiar with toddlers; she wouldn't sit still to even take a picture until I gave her a bottle, and even then I had to sit her on my lap. I say "sort of" accidentally because she bumped her head on the couch a few minutes before and had a huge lump on the right side of her forehead; this was the only picture from the set that hides the bump.

[Larger version](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B1Nib21Gw3tyZTI0MjcxYmQtZWQ0Mi00NTU1LTg5ODYtZGFiNzUwN2U3YzQ5&hl=en_US)