# Weekly Featured Image: Nov 21, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 21 November** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Nov 20th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/weekly-featured-image-nov-14-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 24):

**Jelly Fish**

from Hong Kong

[image]

Canon EOS 60D with EF 50mm f/1.4

Comment: Thank you for the up votes.

Comment: Was this through glass or with an underwater kit?

Comment: through glass :)

Comment: Phenomenal color and crispness. These are hard to shoot well. Great job!

Comment: Thank you, they are indeed not the easiest subjects. Fortunately, it is very slow, unlike many other ocean animals. lol

Comment: amazing colours.

Answer (score 13):

### Center Point

[image: Center Point]

Detail from the ceiling of the Washington, D.C. Metro Center station. Cropped and rotated version of this [photo](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Architecture/Washington-DC-metro/16009410_hgtGtV/1/1204131919_6zQjT#1204132132_EiCBV).

Hand held shot with a full-frame (35mm) dSLR at 42mm, f/2.8, 1/25 and ISO 800.

Comment: Oooohhh.. I love it! My kind of photo. :-)

Answer (score 9):

**Tso Moriri**

[image: Tso Moriri (Moriri Lake), Ladakh]

[Tso Moriri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsomoriri_Wetland_Conservation_Reserve) ('Tso' means Lake in Ladakhi) is one of the highest lakes [4,595 m (15,075 ft)]. A nice, calm and freaking cold place.

**[Large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6323251894/in/photostream/lightbox)**

Comment: Nice to see again. Great colors!

Answer (score 9):

### Train Trestles & Mountain Larches

[image]

Taken in northern Montana - just outside Glacier National Park (US).
The colorful trees are coniferous, known as *[Larches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larch)*.

**[Larger](http://www.flickr.com/photos/studiohack23/6332082461/)** with slightly different dimensions.

Comment: Ah! Glad you submitted this...awesome photograph! Love the mock "miniature" effect, and the scene is pretty amazing.

Comment: @jrista thanks! :)

Comment: Wow I wish I could be in glacier at that time of the year!

Comment: Fun pic. Nice composition, too.

Comment: +1, You have successfully recognised different types of trees from quite a long way away.

Answer (score 8):

### **Kanchenjunga**

[image]

Kanchenjunga, the 3rd highest mountain peak in the world.
Taken with Canon 50mm f/1.8 with a CPL filter held manually in-front of it. Larger and B&W version can be found in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/6344369612/).

Answer (score 7):

### The Missing Screw

[image: The Missing Screw]

Playing with lights (from my mobile phone) and a cheap point & shoot with cool macro capabilities (Canon A410). [Larger Version](http://500px.com/photo/3202855)

Comment: This is actually a really good way of finding lost screws on the floor...

Answer (score 3):

**Cactus Hearts**

[image]

Comment: I vote for this one for next February 14!

Comment: talk about oxymoronic.

Answer (score 1):

## Occupied Harvard

[image: Occupied Harvard, November 15, 2011]

In the category of photojournalism....

November 15th, 2011, Harvard Yard, Cambridge, Massachusetts

Comment: is this part of the Wall Street protests?

Comment: It is related but, as there is no central organization to the general "Occupy" movement (if that's the right word), it's not _part of_ OWS in an official sense. Additionally, as Harvard is not letting people not affiliated with the university into the Yard, it is entirely comprised of Harvard students.

Comment: That background information aside, this is meant as a photojournalism entry, not a political statement.

Comment: @mattdm - and what if it were? Is this kind of context prohibited in this forum?

Comment: BTW - I fill for the poor students out in the cold nights... (although we had some very nice days in the past two weeks). I will have to be pushed out of my heated home.

Comment: @ysap: I don't think it's prohibited per se; it's just not my intent _here_. I don't think that we want overt political statements (for things I agree with or for things I don't) running as the banner of the site, which is the intent of the contest. I don't think the contest is irrelevant, but I also don't think this is the place to discuss it. (Especially because, in this case, it's quite a long and complicated discussion.)

Comment: That said, I will add that it's unfortunately hard to see some of the detail at the required small size, like the police at the gates (the bright yellow uniforms) or the expressions on the students' faces.

Comment: Is there a larger size version of this photo?

Comment: @DiAlex: yes. You can see a larger version in this set on Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattdm/sets/72157628140739164/

Answer (score 1):

[image: A bee taking off from an orange flower]

Click image for large version.

Answer (score 0):

**Candy Shop**

[image]

[Larger](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/GMTD4OPUMg29zu6nUh4yfmpzUQFIr2meqSnjLSkWOnOfAKckanUJ2yQHEmBexZMFlYGtpop3uE5oMeHVGHEVd7bN6Q-kA7uUEnI=w1024)

Comment: I think that a candy shop offers some great opportunity for catching eye-candy, colorful photos. Unfortunately, you decided to concentrate on the somewhat dull glass jars, so I think you missed the potential of the shot. That said, this is *my* opinion and you as the artist are respectfully entitled to have your own.

Comment: Constructive critiques can be helpful to newcomers (though they are actually against the rules stated above), but thinly veiled demeaning of someone's photo is just... Well rude. I think if you don't like something, but are not in a mood to offer helpful positive information, you really should keep your thoughts to yourself, however fluffed they are with platitudes. That said, this is *my* opinion.