# Weekly Featured Image: Nov 28, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 28 November** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Nov 27th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/weekly-featured-image-nov-21-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: So many good ones this week!! :)

Answer (score 25):

### Ooooo, Curves....

[image: Ooooo, Curves....]

Taken at Oxford Circus underground station in London.

You can see the fullsize image version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6189698292/).

Comment: Awesome! Great shot. Is the fish-eye distortion from the lens alone?

Comment: Great shot. I love how peculiar it looks at first, yet it's something quite ordinary. Well done.

Answer (score 18):

### The Morning Skies

[image: The Morning Skies]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/3056902)

Comment: Beautiful! Love the mist...

Comment: Thank you @jrista

Answer (score 17):

### [Hug me!...](http://flic.kr/p/aGnEN8)

[image: danboard]

You can see the original in **[flickr](http://flic.kr/p/aGnEN8)**, **[google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/105678730193466810150/albums/5642730048463888977)** or **[500px](http://500px.com/pacoespinoza)**

1. **Camera:** Nikon D3100
2. **Focal Length:** 55 mm
3. **Shutter Speed:** 1/80 sec
4. **Aperture:** 8
5. **ISO/Film:** 400

Comment: I love this ^_^

Answer (score 12):

## One | many | more

[image: One | many | more]

Original, [larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-10-24) had images not cropped, because there was no limit on aspect ratio.

<sub>Technical info: Three shots at 100mm f/4.5, converted from RAW with Pentax Photo Laboratory, resized and cropped with XnView, arranged and "unsharp mask" in Gimp. Border color is the average color of middle shot.</sub>

Comment: +1 for the title ;)

Comment: +1 for the details :-O

Comment: What is the relationship of the first image to last two (which are the same framing with different focus, right?)

Comment: @mattdm same tree, another branch (closer to camera). And yes, you're right.

Comment: +1 for the story...

Answer (score 11):

**Trees Are Big**

[image]

[Large version](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B047Z1EiZDMrNjM4ZDVmMzQtYjEwNy00MDExLWI3OGMtMGM0MmQ0OWM2NzFi&hl=en_US)

Comment: I liked the framing.

Answer (score 4):

**Berry Berry good** :)

[image: Berries]

You can see the original version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sridhar/6373171351/in/photostream).

Comment: Are those baby blueberries?

Comment: jrista: Not really sure.. didn't see any labels on them nor any ripe ones to be sure..

Answer (score 2):

**Spring fire**

[image: Spring fire]

[Larger version](https://picasaweb.google.com/115868136765822134407/Public#5468628958324881682)
 One of my first photos I took on a DSLR back in 2009 and the first time I've seen this flower.

Answer (score 2):

### Late Autumn Color

[image: late fall colors]

Answer (score 1):

[image: thought this was a good composition!!]

thought this was a good composition!!

Comment: You need to re-read the part of the rules that specify image size.

Comment: Hey are you jogging or joking ?