# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 5, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 5 December** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Dec 4th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/weekly-featured-image-nov-28-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Night Falls at Great Falls

[image: Great Falls, Virginia]

I waited for the sun to set to minimize the contrast between the sky and the Potomac river. It also reduced the overall contrast, so I decided to go to town with the curves, dodge and burn tools in post.

265mm, f/5.6, 5 second exposure at ISO 100.

Larger version [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Nature/Great-Falls-November-2011/20072829_GHmJX5#1594802091_Djr7nnj).

Comment: This si pretty amazing!

Comment: @jrista Thanks! In moderate doses, long exposure of flowing water == instant magic :-)

Comment: I love this, especially the post work!

Comment: I would like to compare this image with the original before the edits.

Comment: @Kim: Indeed...but I love the mood...the water effect is great, but the cool tone and dark atmosphere are really what make it such an awesome photo.

Comment: @JohnIsaacks I'm toying with the idea of writing a blog post that shows the transition from raw to finished image. Perhaps if I end up with a lot of time on my hands during the holidays, but no promises yet :-)

Comment: A before after blog post would be really interesting.

Comment: I would really look forward to that blog, Kim!

Comment: I didn't realize how huge the falls were till I looked at your other images. I thought this image covered maybe 10-15ft across at first, but it looks more like maybe 75-100ft! Awesome!

Comment: @dpollitt You're right. Thanks to the line-drawing tool in Google maps, I estimate the foreground to be about 110 feet wide, taken at a distance of almost 500 feet.

Answer (score 20):

**After Sunset**

[image]

Taken just after sunset near Cape Town, South Africa

Canon 30D, ISO 200, EF70-210mm @ 70mm f/4, 1 second exposure

[Larger](http://photo.net/photodb/photo?photo_id=6403197)

Comment: Glad to see this again. Great Photo!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 16):

### Brule Bay Sunrise

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/3317239)

I used to think that I needed to travel across the world to capture interesting images but lately I am discovering what's in my own back yard.

Comment: Beautiful colors. I'd like to see some depth to the skies color as well, but even though, like it very much!

Comment: Thanks @ysap. The sun is solely responsible for those colours.

Comment: I often like shooting with overcast skies, but I hate having them as a background. Good shot none the less.

Comment: Yeah, if _that's_ in your back yard. :)

Comment: @mattdm - I am not a native speaker but I thought the expression ”in my back yard” could be used to refer to the nearby areas of where I live.  This particular location is 15min away.  Last week’s submission was the same location facing the other way.

Comment: Yes, it does mean that. I was making a little joke. But in any case that's pretty nice to live so close to.

Answer (score 13):

Dad's Obsession

[image: Dad's Obsession]

Full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/5344880728/in/set-72157625797327942), though it doesn't get any better bigger! ;)

Shot with a Nikon D90, Sigma 70-200mm, at 200mm, F2.8, 1/50", ISO 1600, hand-held with no VR, so not as sharp as I would like.

This was taken at Winterfest 2011 (a [Synchronized Skating](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/sets/72157625797327942/) Competition).  Lots of Dads bring cameras to shoot their daughters skating.  I thought this was too funny not to capture.

BTW, I know all 3 of these Dads (my daughter skates with their daughters).  I was actually sitting behind them, but when I saw them line up like this, I ran around to the other side of the rink to capture the image.

Comment: Synchronised shooting :-)

Comment: Just Hilarious!

Comment: Funny shot. I think the WB needs a little adjustment though, it's a bit yellow. Too bad there isn't a shot of all four of you.

Comment: Great capture! Have you considered a black and white version?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'll try the black and white version next week (and that will solve my WB problem too!).  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

### [Hug me!...](http://flic.kr/p/aGnEN8)

[image: danboard]

You can see the original in **[flickr](http://flic.kr/p/aGnEN8)**, **[google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/105678730193466810150/albums/5642730048463888977)** or **[500px](http://500px.com/pacoespinoza)**

1. **Camera:** Nikon D3100
2. **Focal Length:** 55 mm
3. **Shutter Speed:** 1/80 sec
4. **Aperture:** 8
5. **ISO/Film:** 400

Answer (score 12):

## Pocket Wizards and flashes at St. Anthony's

[image: Pocket Wizards and flashes at St. Anthony's]

[Link to full size image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cam-peterson/3607392675/in/photostream)
Canon 1D Mark III - 24-70mm 2.8L
1/3200 sec @ f4 ISO 100
Hypersynced via Pocket Wizard MiniTT1
2 flashes (580ex & SB28) at full power fired remotely with pocket wizard receivers one on either side of me about 3 feet out.

Comment: This needs to be resized according to our rules, as our header can only accommodate images up to a certain size. If this is not resized, we'll need to delete it from this weeks contest.

Comment: I'd upvote it if you re-size it :)

Comment: It also needs a title.

Comment: I second @Shutterbug

Comment: Sorry for the oversized image post at first. And thanks for your patience. :)

Comment: As promised: +1 Nice shot & lighting

Answer (score 10):

**Fall Colors**

[image: Fall Colours]

Comment: This is a magical photo. I'm completely unable to tell why I'm so much in love with it. It is actually a picture I would usually ignore after a brief look, but somehow I just couldn't let go of this one.

Answer (score 9):

**Finding the present in the past..**

[image]

Full size on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sridhar/5524595212/in/set-72157626179846596).

Comment: Ajanta Ellora caves?

Comment: No.. Qutub Minar

Comment: You went "inside" Qutub minar? I thought that's not allowed? Also, I have never been there :)

Comment: :) .. Qutub Minar stands in the middle of some ruins.. This was shot there..

Comment: How many years before did you shoot this? Is it safe to go there with a big camera?

Comment: Took it this feb.. of course it is safe to take your camera there.. all the touristy places are swarming with tourists and cops.. And New Delhi is much safer anyways..

Answer (score 8):

[**The Face-off**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhimanyu-vatsya/5511434289)

[image: The Face-off]

Canon 500D -  Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8

50mm | 1/200 | f/25 | ISO 800

Strobist: Minolta 280PX at approx 1/4th power (Low setting) to the left of the subject through a snoot. Triggered using a Cactus V5.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Solitary...

Comment: +1 I like the tension in this image--between subject and negative space, between peaceful and drama. Do you have a link to a larger version?

Comment: Yes i do. but its a facebook link.. Would that do?
[link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=294057660633854&set=a.284512944921659.70476.175105145862440&type=1&theater)

Answer (score 4):

Redmond Library at Night

[image]

[A larger Version](https://plus.google.com/photos/107413988490959360135/albums/5680130226929369745)

Comment: Great shot! Love the perspective!

Comment: I would have liked to see the shrubbery at the bottom not be cut off, so that it could complete the corner, and maybe just a tiny bit more room at the top but overall I like the colour and perspective. Great shot indeed.

Answer (score 3):

## Oil Painting Sunset

[image: Sunset with vivid reds and yellows]

[Larger version](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/2Aytbr2EgfXgeUexKYUmO79nDNz78DOouxvFt3beX9o?feat=directlink). Taken October 14, 2011 from the Safeway parking lot in Spearfish, South Dakota, USA.

Answer (score 2):

## Birch juice

[image: Birch juice]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-04-17)

Comment: Ooooooh!! My kind of pic! Hope this gets some visibility! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Tractor**

[image]