# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 12, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 12 December** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Dec 11th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/weekly-featured-image-nov-28-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: I know the idea of themes has been discussed, but anyone like the idea of making the next couple weeks with a "holiday" theme?

Comment: I think thats a GREAT idea!

Comment: I just wanted to note that the main page's "Submit your vote" link still links to last week's thread...  (Not sure if I should post that here, or as a "quesetion" on Meta?).

Comment: @seanmc: Fixed.

Answer (score 17):

### Solitude

[image: Solitude]

[Larger version](https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6103/6391250313_ee83ba5619_z.jpg)

Shot on an foggy autumn morning.
I like the atmosphere and the colors of the branches in the trees.

Comment: the life is ending, I walk remembering all the good things that I lived at your side... good picture!...

Comment: Lovely mood to this one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice comments.

Answer (score 12):

## [Indian Bride](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhimanyu-vatsya/5481639779/)

[image: Indian Bride]

Shot this at an Indian wedding ceremony with the **nifty fifty**.

Canon 500D | 50 mm @ f/1.8 | 1/1250 | ISO 800

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/abhimanyu-vatsya/5481639779/)

Comment: Worth upvoting. :)

Comment: May I know which camera and lens do you posses?

Comment: Canon 500D, Tamron 17-50mm f/2.8, Canon 50mm f/1.8 and Canon 18-55 IS (not in use, superseded by the Tamron).

Comment: @ Abhimanyu: You reckon the 17-50mm is worth an upgrade? I have kinda the similar setup without the tamron.

Comment: @Nerds.Dont.Swear: Most certainly. See my post here for reasons why - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/are-the-canon-15-85mm-50mm-f-1-8-adequate-substitutes-for-the-17-55mm-f-2-8/

Comment: @Abhimanyu Offtopic newbie question: Do you for some reason prefer Tamron over Nikon? If yes, then what are the reasons?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Nikon lenses don't work on Canon cameras. Third party manufacturers like Tamron, Tokina, etc. make lenses that work on different mounts i.e. different camera bodies like Canon, Nikon, Sony, etc.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thanks, I didn't know that. BTW, Considering that Tamron lenses might be cheaper than Nikon, is there a quality difference too? Oh! You don't use Nikon you might not be knowing it therefore. :(

Comment: Also, your Tamron lens is VR? OR you carry a tripod everywhere? :)

Comment: I have the non-VR lens. You don't need a tripod for a 17-50 zoom range. Stable hands + wide aperture + slightly high ISO gets you a sufficient shutter speed to handhold.

Comment: okay, but when you zoom in doesn't the aperture raise from 2.8 to 4 or something? Do you get the desired results/bokey then? Or is there a way out? And also if you don't write @Anisha I won't get the notification.

Comment: @AnishaKaul This is a *fixed aperture* lens. The aperture remains f/2.8 even when you zoom in to 50mm. Thats what makes it so much better than the typical kit lenses that come with most cameras.

Comment: Oh that's beautiful, what's the cost in rupees? Must be expensive. :)

Comment: @AnishaKaul INR 21,000

Answer (score 10):

### The Bridge To St Paul's

[image: The Bridge To St Pauls]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6451844135/).

Answer (score 9):

### Dirty Supernova

[image: Dirty Supernova - By Vian Esterhuizen]

Canon 7D | EF 50 mm f/1.8 II @ f/1.8 | 1/8000 | ISO 100

This was an experiment of mine the other day. Saw a nice sunset out my office window but limited myself to taking the photo from within the office. Ended up doing a lot of abstract shots. This is with the focus on the dirty window.

[Larger Version](http://500px.com/photo/3537399)

Comment: Love this one! :)

Comment: I had a feeling you would like this one. :) Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Toronto Sunset

[image: Toronto Sunset]

[Larger version](https://picasaweb.google.com/107507613956941447651/MyPictures#5659472356119238626)

Comment: Love the parallel of ship+wake and tower+cloud.

Answer (score 4):

***Just* a leaf**
[image: Lonely leaf]

Larger [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6247097531/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 3):

## Yes I Shook The Camera!

[image: Close Lightning Strike]

[Larger Image](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/zRPkCqMgm_tp5c8M8nKHMWIO4UeY0NR-bp0RaL5vPCg?feat=directlink).  My Canon T1i, my first SLR, was 3 days old.  I was excited to be getting [lightning photos](https://picasaweb.google.com/111471664614886058938/2010Lightning?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCLuD0qn0yYvR6QE&feat=directlink) on my first try. After 2 hours the storm reached me and its wind-driven rain made me put away the tripod and take hand-held time exposures from inside the car. This bolt hit while I had the shutter open and the flash and immediate crack of thunder made me jump, as you can see by the double-exposed fence posts. I had better photos of my first lightning shoot but none as memorable as this!

Answer (score 3):

## Frostbitten

[image: Frostbitten]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-10-12)

Answer (score 2):

**Shine On**

[image]

Comment: Apples? Cherries? Pomegranates? I can't really tell what those are.

Comment: Crabapples maybe

Comment: They look like rosehips to me.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Indeed, however...on a tree? ;P

Comment: I'm going to agree with Crabapples

Answer (score 1):

### Flowers Shot In Thailand Using a Nikon D90

[image]

Comment: Your picture is the right width by it's 39px too tall.

Comment: Resized! Should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Foggy day in Yercaud, TN, India. It is the backside of the Hotel.]

Shot during the trip from office with colleagues.

Camera: Canon PowerShot A590 IS

Full size image here on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/satya_karan/6410132909/sizes/l/in/set-72157628170509997/).

Comment: The mist is lovely, but I think you might want to give more attention to edges when composing. There's a house which is neither in the picture or out, and lower edge has bitten a leg off the chair.

Comment: yes, that is there.