# Weekly Featured Image: April 2, '12

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This week's contest will run two weeks in a row, to account for the tie last week.  You've got extra time, make some awesome water photos!

---

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 2 April** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on April 1st at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

### **THIS WEEK's theme is WATER**

This theme is the third of a four-week series. The NEXT TWO WEEKS will conform to the theme below. Each week will be for a different element: Earth, Air, Water, Fire. The idea is to depict the ancient "Classical Elements", often involved in magic, fundamental to the workings and creation of the universe. Opposing and complementary.

This week's theme is about the **Classical Element of Water**. All photos must involve this serene element in some way or another. We encourage you to show you creative side here - show us the water in a way we've never seen.
[See full details about the theme here.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/picture-of-the-week-theme-classical-elements-air-for-week-of-march-12-12)

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/weekly-featured-image-mar-19-12)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Apparently the theme is actually 'coast line' lol

Comment: :-). I started it.

Comment: So, this is a "2 week challenge", but people can start voting right away. So in a 2 week span we might get more entries, but really the earliest to enter have a much better chance at getting the largest amount of votes.

Comment: @dpollitt Yup, its just like any other contest we do. Early entries **obviously** have more time, but honestly, its never seemed to be much of an issue. The community votes for good stuff regardless.  For example, last week the two winning photos were entered days after the majority of the entries.  We don't have a way to enforce a different system.

Comment: @dpollitt also see [this question](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/better-way-to-submit-pictures-of-the-week)

Comment: @Vikas - I broke it. :)

Comment: I find it very dissapointing to see that the person who suggested the theme hasn't bothered to post any picture. :mad: ;D ;D

Comment: I'm with Anisha... Why hasn't @mattdm joined the fray?!?

Comment: I'm waiting for the [one about cats](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/a/2046/1943)!

Comment: @mattdm In portraits by candle lights, you can even try the cat as the subject. ;)

Answer (score 18):

### After Sunset

[image]

[Larger Verison](http://500px.com/photo/3449750)

Taken just after sunset near Cape Town, South Africa

Canon 30D, ISO 200, EF70-210mm @ 70mm f/4, 1 second exposure

I believe this is my last chance with this particular photo but if there were ever a week for it, this would be the one.

Comment: Nice and moody! :)

Comment: @jaxxon Thank you :) This is one of my oldest photographs but also one my my favourites. So low budget, I still have nicks on my 30D from resting it on rocks to take this pictures. Nicks and scratches of pride! :P

Answer (score 12):

### Splash

[image: Splash]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5502105306/).

Comment: Nice moment captured. Like the contrast.. B&W is a good choice!

Answer (score 10):

**Water Always Wins**

[image]

Give it some time and it will cut through mountains to find its way. This beach is one place where cracks, stacks and other structures are evidence of power of water.

[Davenport, California](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6860653741/in/set-72157629280503343/lightbox)

Answer (score 7):

**Seagull at Hug Point**

[image: seagull on a rock ignoring the waves]

He didn't even flinch as the waves washed over him.

(resubmit from *almost exactly* [one year ago](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/875/2910)!)

Comment: Hahaha, this one makes me laugh

Answer (score 5):

**Falls**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a larger version of this? Not for the contest; I just want to see...

Comment: http://365project.org/mikew/365/2012-02-04

Comment: Beautiful!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

## Winter Cushions

[image: Winter Cushions]

Nobody said it had to be *liquid* water! [Larger version on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5337037176/in/set-72157624954209095/)

Comment: "Nobody said it had to be liquid water!" A good one. :hattip:

Comment: @AnishaKaul - Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

### Wet Feet

[image: Wet Feet]

Answer (score 3):

#### Priceless view

[image: Classic]

[FlickR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6856429278/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 2):

### Relief...

[image]

["Enclicken to Embiggen at Flickr...en"](http://flic.kr/p/8jYezX)

Taken at out yearly block party. In 2010 the Chicago area was in the middle of a heat wave and our fire dept. came out like they do every year to show off the fire engine and equipment to the kids. The firefighters though it would be fun to cool the kids off the easy way.

[A view from the other end of the hose.](http://flic.kr/p/8jYf6e)

Answer (score 2):

**Puzzling**

[image: Puzzling]

Not exactly what I was hoping for, but probably the best I’ll manage before the end of water week…

Comment: What am I looking at?

Comment: Ice cubes in puzzle piece shapes is my guess

Comment: @rfusca:  Vian Esterhuizen was spot on, it's a bunch of ice cubes.  I was really looking to get a bit more underlighting to bring the colour in the pieces out more, but couldn't quite get it to work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hai

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably submitting too late, but here's my water picture:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This picture is taken at a very bright sunny day. I was looking at the sky with my friends, we both had sunglasses on. Suddenly this cloud came in front of the sun and it looked all very epic. We thought of this story regarding the cloud: it was as if we were looking from below at Icarus falling into the sea. The sun rays to the left being one of the wings (I could not get the other wing into the frame, but it was there), the cloud being his back cutting through the water creating all this turbulence. I took a picture of "Icarus" with my analog camera through my polarised sunglasses. Hope you like it.

tl;dr: A cloud is water too. Taken through my polaroid sunglasses with a Praktica MTL-3

[image: Clouds are water too]

Answer (score 0):

Image was taken in Dahab, Egypt where water looks very clear and you can see objects underwater.

Larger version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mellice/7027178331/in/photostream)

[image: Clear Water]

Answer (score 0):

**Falling Diamonds..**

[image]

Taken in Nottingham City Center..

Mode: Shutter Priority.. 1/4000s, f1.8, ISO 100 -1EV

Comment: Hi Flowerking and welcome to the contest. You'll need to post this in the correct dimensions per the rules "Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide".