# Image of the week "hall of fame" (2011 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning in reverse chronological order.

**This is the Hall of Fame Archive for 2011**.

[**26 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1746) - [Matt Grum](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1375)
[Express Delivery - Matt Grum http://www.mattgrum.com/photo_se/express_delivery.png](http://www.mattgrum.com/photo_se/express_delivery.png)

[**19 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1726) - [jrista](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124)
[image: The Snowman vs. the Flame - jrista]

[**12 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1697) - [Arcadie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3922)
[image: Solitude - Arcadie]

[**5 December 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1672) - [Kim Brgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: Night Falls at Great Falls - Kim Burgaard]

[**28 November 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1645) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Ooooo, Curves.... - Sean]

[**21 November 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1629) - [Gapton](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6745)
[image: Jelly Fish - Gapton]

[**14 November 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1614) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977)
[image: Lonely and Cold - Jakub]

[**7 November 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1593) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Prow - jaxxon]

[**31 October 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1570) - [fluf](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3782)
[image: Morning - fluf]

[**24 October 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551) - [jrista](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124)
[image: Dandelion - jrista]

[**17 October 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1525) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Prisoner - jaxxon]

[**10 October 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510) - [Mark Whitaker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3644)
[image: Keaton the merry-go-round horse - Mark Whitaker]

[**3 October 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1491) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Looking Into The Future - jaxxon]

[**26 September 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1470) - [Kim Burgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: Under the Rockies - Kim Burgaard]

[**19 September 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Way Out - Sean]

[**12 September 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417) - [Mark Whitaker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3644)
[image: Where rainbows come from - Mark Whitaker]

[**5 September 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417) - [intoTHEwild](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1209)
[image: Bluetooth - intoTHEwild]

[**29 August 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1387) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Solar Flare - jaxxon]

[**22 August 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1358) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Going Northbound On The Bakerloo - sean]

[**15 August 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1341) - [dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4892)
[image: Jolly Beach - dpollitt]

[**8 August 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1322) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Colored Window Grid - jaxxon]

[**1 August 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1306) - [Kim Burgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: Tunnel Vision - Kim Burgaard]

[**25 July 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1291) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Droplets - jaxxon]

[**18 July 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1274) - [ElendilTheTall](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3205)
[image: Three Droplets - ElendilTheTall]

[**11 July 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252) - [pacoespinoza](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4727)
[image: Team working... - pacoespinoza]

[**4 July 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1212) - [D. Lambert](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/269)
[image: Giving me the Eye - D. Lambert]

[**27 June 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1188) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Orb of Life - jaxxon]

[**20 June 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1166) - [ElendilTheTall](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3205)
[image: Twist - ElendilTheTall]

[**13 June 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1154) - [jaxxon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5336)
[image: Ready to Draw - jaxxon]

[**6 June 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127) - [Lazer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/64)
[image: Light at the End - Lazer]

[**31 May 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1114) - [Jin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4)
[image: Niagara at Night - Jin]

[**24 May 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Anyone For Ice Cream? - Sean]

[**16 May 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1093) - [Maynard Case](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2127)
[image: Antelope Canyon - Maynard Case]

[**9 May 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1068) - [pacoespinoza](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4727)
[image: A sunset in the Valley - pacoespinoza]

[**2 May 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023) - [Arcadie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3922)
[image: Sadness - Arcadie]

[**25 April 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1002) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Light Trails To The Beatles - Sean]

[**18 April 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/972) - [Kim Burgaard](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2559)
[image: Web Frame - Kim Burgaard]

[**11 April 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/952) - [Sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697)
[image: Poplar DLR Bridge - Sean]

[**4 April 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/914) - [ile](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3614)
[image: Blue Laguna Hvar - ile]

[**28 March 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/886)
[image: On the Wing - D. Lambert]

[**21 March 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/864) - [Joanne C](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/472)
[image: In Your Dreams - Joanne C]

[**14 March 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/847) - [Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149)
[image: Evening falls - Guffa]

[**7 March 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825) - [D.N.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4002)
[image: Influential Beggar - D.N.]

[**28 February 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/791) - [rfusca](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1917)
[image: Deep Red - rfusca]

[**21 February 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/766) - [Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149)
[image: Sunset - Guffa]

[**14 February 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/728) - [Jay Lance Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2838)
[image: Playing With Fire - Jay Lance Photography]

[**7 February 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/696) - [Si Keep B](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/823)
[image: Weathered Posts - Si Keep]

[**31 January 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663) - [Sergiu B](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3357)
[image: Water Bokeh - Sergiu B]

[**24 January 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/636) - [friol](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3231)
[image: Invaders - friol]

[**17 January 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593)
[image: Flower Market in Hoxton, London - Maynard Case]

[**10 January 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571) - [Si Keep](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/823)
[image: Beach at Padstow, Cornwall - Si Keep]

[**3 January 2011**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560) - [Joanne C](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/472)
[image: Spring is Coming - Joanne C]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)