# Weekly featured image - how to increase the entries?

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

I am surprised at the small number of entries in the "weekly featured image" series.
A semi random look at some past entries showed 2 with 8 entries and 3 with 12. So far this week there are 3 and last week I think 5.

In a group dedicated to photography I'd have thought there would be many more willing to "have a go". I realise that it can be quite challenging to submit a photo that you personally like for some reason and have it given low ratings by the group, but the drop from 12 or so to 3 or 4 suggests a stronger disincentive.

Are people aware of the feature - "just" having it written on the top of the screen is easily enough missed. I stumbled over it by mistake only, after having it literally in front of my eyes.

How can this be promoted?
 Should it be?
 ...?

Comment: It's *good* to have just 3 or 4 -- there's a better chance of winning! ;)

Comment: I've been on this site for many months and I just found out about it a week or two ago! Not sure why it took me so long...

Comment: It's been _at least_ a week since I've seen a subway/tunnel picture of the week, so someone will surely pop in and post one of those.

Comment: Erm, subways and tunnels will probably be me!

Answer (score 9):

For discussion, here are the number of entries from the last 74 contests, which I think is all of them (the last number in this list is from [Weekly Featured Image: Nov. 4, '10](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/weekly-featured-image-nov-4-10)).

5
6
8
8
10
9
7
15
11
8
7
6
4
9
8
11
11
13
7
10
9
10
6
8
11
7
9
8
12
12
14
12
12
13
8
9
8
7
12
7
7
10
5
7
10
9
4
10
8
5
7
9
10
6
5
7
9
11
9
7
9
8
10
8
6
8
4
6
7
3
10
11
12
12

(The most-recent on the left, the oldest on the right.)

[image: simple graph of the numbers above]

(I see "75% of the time we have 7-12 entries, with 14 weeks below that and 4 above, and right now we're working on the fourth-ever streak of 2 weeks outside that range.")

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $2 ]
then
    echo " -- Usage: $0 <first_url> <num_pages_to_test> -- "
    exit 1
fi

count=1
max=$2
next_url=$1

while [ $count -le $max ]
do
    if [ $count -gt 1 ]
    then
        sleep 2
    fi

    this_url=$next_url
#    page=$(curl -s $this_url)
    page=$(wget -O - -q $this_url)
    next_url=$(echo $page | sed -n 's/.*href=\"\(.*\)\">Last [Ww]eek.s [Tt]hread.*/\1/p')
    answers=$(echo $page | sed -n 's/.*<h2>\([0-9][0-9]*\) Answers<\/h2>.*/\1/p')
    echo "$answers, $this_url"
    if [ -z $next_url ]
    then
        echo "Error getting next URL, exiting."
        exit 2
    fi
    let count=$count+1
done

echo "Reached max count ($max)."
```

Comment: The upvote is for posting the source :)

Answer (score 2):

Today I once again thought about the "picture of the week", and that I should submit a few of my photos. Then I realised that this weeks "competition" is just about to finish (tonight / Sunday night) and that next weeks thread will be started tomorrow (Monday).

What I find is that almost always remember PotW during the weekend, but then it's a bit pointless to submit a photo.

Maybe we should start next weeks thread on Saturdays or Sundays, not on Monday. That way people can submit next weeks photo while they have a bit of spare time during the weekend.

I'm not sure this would help, but I think it would make it easier for me to submit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of the feature (since a couple of weeks ago), and don't think it needs (or can easily get) greater visibility.

I'm mainly mulling over which photos I could submit, or I'd probably have done it already.

Answer (score 0):

The contest has always been linked to from the banner since we came out of beta (i.e. as long as we've had the contest).

It may just be a perception that there are few entries, but think of it as your chance to stand a better chance :)