# Image of the week “hall of fame” (2010 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning in reverse chronological order.

**This is the Hall of Fame Archive for 2010**.

[**27 December 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549) - [Rowland Shaw](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21)
[image: Shore Ice - Rowland Shaw]

[**20 December 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/531) - [Zoe Bailey](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1907)
[image: Happy holidays - Zoe Bailey]

[**13 December 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/520) - [uberto](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2507)
[image: Andalusia - uberto]

[**6 December 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/509) - [Joanne C](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/472)
[image: Up in Smoke - Joanne C]

[**29 November 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/488) - [MJeffryes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2269)
[image: Girona, Spain - Ziggamorph]

[**22 November 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/471) - [Alan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/170)
[image: Koln, Germany - Alan]

[**11 November 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434) - [Stormenet](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1937)
[image: Calais, France - Stormenet]

[**4 November 2010**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/387) - [sebastien.b](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1273)
[image: Thanksgiving Fog - sebastien.b]