# Image of the Week "Hall of Fame" (2013 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of the current year in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

[**26 December 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Frank](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20069/frank)
[image: Tree Lizard - Frank]

[**17 December 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Leah](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2243/leah)
[image: Early Morning Stonehenge - Leah]

[**10 December 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Paul Cezanne](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7310/paul-cezanne)
[image: A Mysterious Shot - Paul Cezanne]

[**03 December 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Kangaroo business meeting - adjourned!!! - Russell McMahon]

[**26 November 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Mari](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14384/mari)
[image: Early Morning Sun Rise Near Sea Shore - Mari]

[**19 November 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Himanshu Punetha](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21157/himanshu-punetha)
[image: Oriental Garden Lizard - Himanshu Punetha]

[**12 November 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Meysam](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8756/meysam)
[image: Yasna - یسنا - Meysam]

[**05 November 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Fanis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3837/fanis)
[image: Sunset above Palaios Drys, Cyprus mountains - Fanis]

[**29 October 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Beauty is in the mind of the beholder. - Russell McMahon]

[**23 October 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [edilsonfb](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21689/edilsonfb)
[image: It's just a few drops of water - edilsonfb]

[**16 October 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Rafal Ziolkowski](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1681/rafal-ziolkowski)
[Saint Lake at sunrise in Pushkar, India - Rafal Ziolkowski http://www.the-zet.com/share/RZ_20121116_005706.jpg](http://www.the-zet.com/share/RZ_20121116_005706.jpg)

[**08 October 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Johan Bezem](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14136/johan-bezem)
[image: Istanbul, Sehzade Mehmed Mosque, April 4th, 2008 - Johan Bezem]

[**01 October 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Conor Boyd](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1124/conor-boyd)
[image: Castle Hill Village from Wuthering Heights, Canterbury NZ - Conor Boyd]

[**24 September 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [epoon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/15626/epoon)
[image: Mori Tower - epoon]

[**17 September 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399/garik)
[image: Boats in the fire - Octopus]

[**10 September 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Octopus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/17634/octopus)
[image: Island Sunset - Octopus]

[**03 September 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Apple Orchard in Fog - Jakub]

[**27 August 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [gsharp](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1361/gsharp)
[image: The Blue Danger - gsharp]

[**15 August 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [pierre](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/19336/pierre)
[image: Aurora Borealis - pierre]

[**29 July 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Paul Cezanne](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7310/paul-cezanne)
[image: Noon's Landing - Paul Cezanne]

[**16 July 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Conor Boyd](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1124/conor-boyd)
[image: Ooops! - Conor Boyd]

[**09 July 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [epoon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/15626/epoon)
[image: Kyoto Falls - epoon]

[**02 July 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [D3C4FF](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14506/d3c4ff)
[image: Melbourne Cables - D3C4FF]

[**24 June 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [AJ Henderson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11392/aj-henderson)
[image: Night Over Camp Gorham - AJ Henderson]

[**18 June 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Linus Kleen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13554/linus-kleen)
[image: Autumn... - Linus Kleen]

[**11 June 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Bart Arondson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/bart-arondson)
[image: A field in Denmark - Bart Arondson]

[**04 June 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Abhranil Das](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5619/abhranil-das)
[image: Cheshire Grin - Abhranil Das]

[**28 May 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Starry Starry Night - Russell McMahon]

[**21 May 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399/garik)
[image: Apples - garik]

**Note: Week of May 14th was skipped to use the banner for some site advertising.**

[**07 May 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Moonrise & Aurora - Jakub]

[**23 April 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Great Grey Owl - Jakub]

[**16 April 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vivek](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6212/vivek)
[image: Cherry Blossoms in Toronto... - Vivek]

[**09 April 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Abhranil Das](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5619/abhranil-das)
[image: A Golden Morning - Abhranil Das]

[**02 April 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vikas](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2773/vikas)
[image: A Golden Morning - Vikas]

[**26 March 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jules Mazur](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8268/jules-mazur)
[image: Golden Gate - Jules Mazur]

[**19 March 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Paul Cezanne](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7310/paul-cezanne)
[image: Noon's Landing - Paul Cezanne]

[**12 March 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Bart Arondson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/bart-arondson)
[image: Smoke Curl - Bart Arondson]

[**05 March 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen)
[image: Boiling - Vian Esterhuizen]

[**28 February 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Abhranil Das](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5619/abhranil-das)
[image: Mountains on the Horizon - Abhranil Das]

[**18 February 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: A Pyramid - Jakub]

[**11 February 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Michael Nielsen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11455/michael-nielsen)
[image: Sweet Dreams - Michael Nielsen]

[**4 February 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Giuseppe iPichy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13518/giuseppe-ipichy)
[image: Motion in Cordusio square Milano - Giuseppe iPichy]

[**28 January 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [dpollitt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4892/dpollitt)
[image: Lake Calhoun in the Snow - dpollitt]

[**22 January 2013**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Winter Calm - Jakub]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)