# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2014 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of the current year in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

[**30 December 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [sunset_star](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7895/sunset-star)
[image: The evening star - Venus - sunset_star]

[**15 December 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [damn truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
[image: Open - damn truths]

[**01 December 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vikas](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2773/vikas)
[image: A Warm Welcome - Vikas]

[**18 November 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Bart Arondson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/bart-arondson)
[image: Incense - Bart Arondson]

[**06 November 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [restlake](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14080/restlake)
[image: Dragonfly - restlake]

[**21 October 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [garik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3399/garik)
[image: Serene Life - garik]

[**10 October 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jorge Córdoba](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26180/jorge-c%c3%b3rdoba)
[image: Westminster fountain at sunset - Jorge Córdoba]

[**26 September 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: The Sleeping Giant's Sea Lion - Jakub]

[**18 September 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20961/jon)
[image: Paris - Jon]

[**09 September 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [w.hrybok](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24537/w-hrybok)
[image: Evening - w.hrybok]

[**30 August 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Road Train !!!!!!!!!! - Russell McMahon]

[**21 August 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Aditya](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1932/aditya)
[image: Forgotten in its old age - Aditya]

[**08 August 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [clabacchio](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7984/clabacchio)
[image: Time passes by - clabacchio]

[**01 August 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [VonSchnauzer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26086/vonschnauzer)
[image: Summer Start - VonSchnauzer]

[**24 July 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Lars Kotthoff](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/16037/lars-kotthoff)
[image: An alley in Pisa, Italy - Lars Kotthoff]

[**17 July 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Bart Arondson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/bart-arondson)
[image: Not Your Everyday Banana - Bart Arondson]

[**09 July 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [NULLZ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14506/nullz)
[image: The Perfect Sunrise - NULLZ]

[**02 July 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Giammarco Boscaro](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26932/giammarco-boscaro)
[Tramonto a Rialto - Giammarco Boscaro http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3746/12754344205_69d294f7cf_n.jpg](http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3746/12754344205_69d294f7cf_n.jpg)

[**24 June 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [kmonsoor](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14226/kmonsoor)
[image: Captive Stare - kmonsoor]

[**18 June 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [damned truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
[image: Bridge Couple - damned truths]

[**10 June 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Hermann Klecker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/17711/hermann-klecker)
[image: Cartolina Postale Veneciana - Hermann Klecker]

[**03 June 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Riot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27217/riot)
[image: Ecliptic - Riot]

[**27 May 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [fahad.hasan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2476/fahad-hasan)
[image: Baby Shrimp and Mom - fahad.hasan]

[**20 May 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149/guffa)
[image: Dinner Table - Guffa]

[**13 May 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [jrista](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/124/jrista)
[image: HDR Moon - jrista]

[**06 May 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Wok](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1741/wok)
[image: Dots of color - Wok]

[**29 April 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [D. Lambert](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/269/d-lambert)
[image: Pftthhhbt! - D. Lambert]

[**22 April 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [ceinmart](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21510/ceinmart)
[image: Orquid "Phoenix" - ceinmart]

[**15 April 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [sat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1980/sat)
[image: Time to be with your loved ones - sat]

[**08 April 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakob](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: 41 minutes later - Jakob]

[**01 April 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [rony36](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/19263/rony36)
[image: Decrepitude - rony36]

[**25 March 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Amritpal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24267/amritpal)
[image: Festival of Lights - Amritpal]

[**18 March 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Dhruva Ghosh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/19280/dhruva-ghosh)
[image: Squirreling - Dhruva Ghosh]

[**11 March 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Frozen Pinewood River - Jakub]

[**04 March 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [faleichik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/22509/faleichik)
[image: Minsk Zoo - faleichik]

[**25 February 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [lalli](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1438/lalli)
[image: View from A Fort - lalli]

[**18 February 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [crimson_penguin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4791/crimson-penguin)
[image: Snowflake on Mohair - crimson_penguin]

[**11 February 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Alex](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9703/alex)
[image: Time Does Not Wait - Alex]

[**04 February 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [IconicPhotos.co.uk](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8629/iconicphotos-co-uk)
[image: The London Eye - IconicPhotos.co.uk]

[**28 January 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Fanis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3837/fanis)
[image: Stormy sunset on the beach, Limassol, Cyprus - Fanis]

[**21 January 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [intoTHEwild](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1209/intothewild)
[image: Fort in Jaipur, India - intoTHEwild]

[**14 January 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [clabacchio](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7984/clabacchio)
[image: Modern World - clabacchio]

[**07 January 2014**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vivek](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6212/vivek)
[image: Sailing into the Night - Vivek]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)