# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2015 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of 2015 in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

[**21 Dec 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [circle-b](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9489/circle-b)
[image: Moo - circle-b]

[**12 Dec 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: High Falls - Jakub]

[**05 Dec 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [nublodeveloper](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24683/nublodeveloper)
[image: Sun setting behind Mount Teide - nublodeveloper]

[**28 Nov 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [darkhausen](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38190/darkhausen)
[image: Eye of the eclipse... - darkhausen]

[**20 Nov 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Pakman](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27409/pakman)
[image: Slains Castle - Pakman]

[**29 Oct 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [fejesjoco](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21975/fejesjoco)
[image: Ocean in the sunset - fejesjoco]

[**15 Oct 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Moonset before Sunrise - Jakub]

[**06 Oct 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [BJHStudios](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24208/bjhstudios)
[image: Dracula's Castle - BJHStudios]

[**24 Sep 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24174/rmano)
[image: High Falls, Pigeon River - Jakub]

[**09 Sep 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Rmano](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24174/rmano)
[image: Red Cabin in snow - Rmano]

[**24 Aug 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [ceinmart](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21510/ceinmart)
[image: Lightnings taking a ride - ceinmart]

[**28 Jul 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Mist - Jakub]

[**08 Jul 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jorge Córdoba](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26180/jorge-c%c3%b3rdoba)
[image: Train to nowhere - Jorge Córdoba]

[**23 Jun 2015**](http://500px.com/photo/22798861) - [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen)
[image: It's a bird - Vian Esterhuizen]

[**27 May 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Moonlight - Jakub]

[**20 May 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Gordon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/471/gordon)
[image: Red and Blue - Gordon]

[**7 May 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Matthew Dresser](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3263/matthew-dresser)
[image: Hudson River - Matthew Dresser]

[**18 April 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [MrFrench](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/31320/mrfrench)
[image: Sunset in Kruger - MrFrench]

[**09 April 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [fahad.hasan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2476/fahad-hasan)
[image: Red Cherry Shrimp - fahad.hasan]

[**02 April 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149/guffa)
[image: Spruce needles - Guffa]

[**25 March 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [peter_budo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/5216/peter-budo)
[image: I Dare You! - peter_budo]

[**15 March 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [drfrogsplat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/889/drfrogsplat)
[image: Farm at Night - drfrogsplat]

[**06 March 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Frosty Morning - Jakub]

[**23 February 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Rodrigo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3930/rodrigo)
[image: Butterfly - Rodrigo]

[**05 February 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Olli](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/3810/olli)
[image: Sagrada Familia - Olli]

[**27 January 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [adarsha joisa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28293/adarsha-joisa)
[image: Fresh Dew on a Rose - adarsha joisa]

[**19 January 2015**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen)
[image: Watching Over - Vian Esterhuizen]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659)
- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)