# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2016 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of 2016 in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end

## Hall of Fame

[**25 December 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [russell mcmahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Seeking support - russell mcmahon]

[**17 December 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [sam](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/29722/sam)
[image: The Forgotten Gully - sam]

[**07 December 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [olin lathrop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7603/olin-lathrop)
[image: Yeah, and what do you want on our mountain? - olin lathrop]

[**30 November 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [paul-cezanne](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/7310/paul-cezanne)
[image: We Forgot Bobby - paul-cezanne]

[**23 November 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [hermann-klecker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/17711/hermann-klecker)
[image: Munich, Karlsplatz - hermann-klecker]

[**16 November 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [damned-truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
[image: Ancient Reflected Beauty - damned-truths]

[**6 November 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [harsh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9554/harsh)
[image: Random clicks - harsh]

[**23 October 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [amritpal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24267/amritpal)
[image: Golden Temple, Amritsar, India - amritpal]

[**14 October 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [eirenaios](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/39617/eirenaios)
[image: Into the Himalayas - eirenaios]

[**05 October 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [cody](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9347/cody)
[image: D.C. Cherry Blossoms- cody]

[**27 September 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [jorge-córdoba](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26180/jorge-c%C3%B3rdoba)
[image: Enchanted - jorge-córdoba]

[**19 September 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [d4rk](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/44610/d4rk)
[image: Clonmacnoise Monastery, Ireland - d4rk]

[**12 September 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [lars-kotthoff](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/16037/lars-kotthoff)
[image: Church ruins in Antigua, Guatemala - lars-kotthoff]

[**04 September 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Riot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27217/riot)
[image: Shade - Riot]

[**28 August 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [jakub](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4977/jakub)
[image: Thistle - jakub]

[**20 August 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [vaddadi-kartick](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22575/vaddadi-kartick)
[image: Train - vaddadi-kartick]

[**12 August 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [web-tiki](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24826/web-tiki)
[image: Sandscape - web-tiki]

[**03 August 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [himanshu-punetha](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21157/himanshu-punetha)
[image: Honeybee - himanshu-punetha]

[**26 July 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [evan-pak](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13254/evan-pak)
[image: Before the rush - evan-pak]

[**18 July 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq

[image: Antarctica - ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq]

[**09 July 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [himanshu-tyagi](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/31835/himanshu-tyagi)
[image: The Living Bridge - himanshu-tyagi]

[**28 June 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [damned-truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
[image: Shadowy Daisy- damned-truths]

[**21 June 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [ani](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/14213/ani)
[image: Spring 2012- ani]

[**06 June 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [toniedzwiedz](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/35320/toniedzwiedz)
[image: Breakwater - toniedzwiedz]

[**29 May 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Meysam](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8756/meysam)
[image: Glasses - Meysam]

[**18 May 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Saaru Lindestøkke](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/saaru-lindest%C3%B8kke)
[image: Nidelva river through Trondheim, Norway - Saaru Lindestøkke]

[**09 May 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [michael-nielsen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11455/michael-nielsen)
[image: Slovenia is Beautiful - michael-nielsen]

[**24 Apr 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [octopus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/17634/octopus)
[image: Napioa - Wind Origins - octopus]

[**09 Apr 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [rga](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24651/rga)
[image: Kilyur waterfalls - rga]

[**30 Mar 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [noldor130884](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/35383/noldor130884)
[image: Chao Praya River, Bangkok - noldor130884]

[**14 Mar 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [monotux](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2017/monotux)
[image: Lake Sannaren, Sweden - monotux]

[**03 Mar 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [lalli](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1438/lalli)
[image: Sparkly Things - lalli]

[**21 Feb 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [frank](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20069/frank)
[image: Parrot in the Shade - frank]

[**08 Feb 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [matt-ball](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1961/matt-ball)
[image: India Point Park - matt-ball]

[**27 Jan 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [andy-m](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20577/andy-m)
[image: Lunch atop a Springfield skyscraper - andy-m]

[**18 Jan 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [sean](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/697/sean)
[image: Alonzo's Church - sean]

[**10 Jan 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Captain Claptrap](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28171/captain-claptrap)
[image: Colorado Cottonwood in Fresh Snow - Captain Claptrap]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2015](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043)
- [Hall of Fame 2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659)
- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)