# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2017 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of the current year in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

[**17 December 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Matthieu Moy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/40449/matthieu-moy)
[image: 22° halo - Matthieu Moy]

[**7 December 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Syed Umar Ahmed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13494/syed-umar-ahmed)
[image: Untitled - Syed Umar Ahmed]

[**16 November 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [rcs](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24876/rcs) 
[image: Sunset- rcs]

Larger: https://www.flickr.com/photos/93042890@N07/16624886930/

[**31 October 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Tim Medora](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20122/tim-medora) 
[image: Lightning strike - tim-medora]

```
13s @ f2.8 ISO 100
Canon 6D/Rokinon 14mm/Giottos tripod
```

[Larger version][1]

[**21 October 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Halil Ibrahim](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/22409/halil-ibrahim)
[image: Build machines - halil-ibrahim]

```
SLT-A37
1/5 f/5.6 ISO 800 50.0 mm
50mm F1.7 Minolta
```

[Larger version on Flickr][2]

[**11 October 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [donovan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24664/donovan)
[image: Build machines - donovan]

[**01 October 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Jorge Córdoba](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26180/jorge-c%C3%B3rdoba)
[image: Build machines - Jorge Córdoba]

NIKON D7000 ISO 200, f/4.5 18mm. Full size: https://flic.kr/p/mbTD5K

[**20 September 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [sarge-borsch](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/32276/sarge-borsch)
[image: A lake near Perkjärv- sarge-borsch]

[**11 September 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [feetwet](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27832/feetwet)
[image: Untitled - feetwet]

Teaspoon under a street cafe's umbrella.  I was mesmerized by the way the handle transformed the umbrella's spokes.  I only had my phone's camera handy.  Fortunately when the subject presents itself that can be all it takes.

[Full size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkxua.jpg)

[**04 September 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Amritpal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24267/amritpal)
[image: Random Flower in Lawn - Amritpal]

[**28 August 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [A K](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/40058/a-k)
[image: Untitled - A K]

[**21 August 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Matthieu Moy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/40449/matthieu-moy)
[image: Untitled - Matthieu Moy]
[Full size](http://mmoy.piwigo.com/picture?/1727/category/15-nature)

It's a [Thomisidae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomisidae), sometimes called "crab spider". Usually lives on a flower, waiting for insects to come. It can even change color and become yellow to hide better on yellow flowers.

[**14 August 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Tetsujin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/57929/tetsujin)
[image: Buick Sunset - Tetsujin]

<sup>Full size on [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGF64.jpg)</sup>

Ironically, taken the day after I got my new camera... but didn't have it with me,
so this was shot on an iPhone.

Hard crop on the left to remove some very ugly buildings & emphasise the lighting. The additional lighting through & underneath the car, & also the highlighting on the front grille were actually coincidental & fortuitous.
I was on location for a movie, on the tarmac at a small airport. The set is behind me; the car wasn't in the scene so was parked off to one side. The lighting was therefore 'just there'.

It's had some cleanup in Photoshop [& the irritating distraction of another hopeful photographer 100yds away, right in the middle of the shot removed] but far less added colour-punch than you would think - it really did look very much like that on the day. It doesn't hurt at all the the car is actually dark purple anyway.

*Edit:* I just realised - for anyone thinking the wet tarmac matches neither the sky nor the dry car - it's because the set had been wet down for the scene... again totally fortuitous.

[**07 August 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [riot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27217/riot)
[image: Golden - riot]

Higher-res view and more info: http://fav.me/dcxbr1

[**25 July 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [arkadi](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/47800/arkadi)
[image: Comarch Oddział Warszawa - arkadi]

Exif: 18mm / ƒ/16 / 1/30s / ISO 400

[**17 July 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Alex](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9703/alex)
[image: Game of Geometry - Alex]

[Original Version](http://500px.com/photo/34297682)

```
Camera Canon EOS 650D
Lens Canon 50mm
Focal Length 50mm
Shutter Speed 1/400 sec
Aperture f/4
ISO/Film 100
```

[**10 July 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Greg](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1440/greg)
[image: Untitled - Greg]

City panorama taken in Budapest, Hungary from the Gellert Hill. Nikon D610 + 18-35mm

[**03 July 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
[image: Assembly - mattdm]

I really liked the colors of this construction site, with the orange safety fence and the cyan/blue-green insulation. But, I couldn't find an angle which really made it interesting, until I found this mirror at a nearby intersection. (Click for larger version.)

[**27 June 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Brad Nesom](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10050/brad-nesom)
[image: Untitled - Brad Nesom]

[**18 June 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [floyd-pink](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4431/floyd-pink)
[image: Yet Another Dusk- floyd-pink]

Clicked at Ocean City, Maryland with a Canon Rebel XSi and an EF-S 10-22mm. Processed single raw as an HDR in Digital Photo Professional.  Larger Image: [500px][3]

[**10 June 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [aditya](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1932/aditya)
[image: Upon us all, a little rain must fall- aditya]

[**31 May 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm)
[image: This Area is Being Videotaped- mattdm]

[**09 May 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [horaciux](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28264/horaciux)
[image: Seagull - horaciux]

[**28 April 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [matthieu-moy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/40449/matthieu-moy)
[image: Refuge de la Glière - matthieu-moy]

[Larger image][4]

[**21 April 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [andy-m](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20577/andy-m)
[image: Friendship - andy-m]

```
    Canon EOS 6D
    Lens : EF100mm f/2.8 Macro USM
    Focal Length : 100mm
    Shutter Speed : 1/2 s
    Aperture : f/14
    ISO/Film : 1600
```

Larger version on [500px][5]

[**14 April 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [goodsp33d](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11367/goodsp33d)
[image: Aero India 2013 - goodsp33d]

[**06 April 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [michal](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/51308/michal)
[image: Library foyer - michal]

[Full size][6]

```
Camera: Nikon D5000
Lens: 18-105/3.5-5.6 AF-S
Focal lenght: 18 mm
Apperture: f/8
ISO: 1600
```

[**30 March 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [olin-lathrop](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/olin-lathrop)
[image: Thru the Aspen Forest - olin-lathrop]

[Larger version][7]

*I really liked the way the morning light filtered thru the aspens on this hike up Escudilla in eastern Arizona on 14 August 2013. The lower part of the trail from the road at Terry Flat predominantly passes thru this aspen forest.*

[**19 March 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [russell-mcmahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Shanghai Tower - looking down - russell-mcmahon]

Larger slightly wider version [here][8].

*Taken from the (non)-viewing gallery at the upper level in the Shanghai tower.
A rail + cables barrier fence and here is provided 2+ metres back from the glassless sloping viewing "window" 
which itself has anti-suicide cables strung across it. No downwards view. 
You have to climb up (not over) the 'fence,' lean out over it, 
support your feet somewhere to balance, hold the camera at arm's length pointing down 
(well secured by strap) and hope you've got it right.*

[**11 March 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [tim-medora](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20122/tim-medora)
[image: Jumping spider - tim-medora]

Larger image: http://medoragroup.com/share/img_9278.jpg

```
Canon 6D
MPE-65 @ roughly 1.5x
ISO 2500, 1/320s, f/6.3
Ring light + sunlight
```

[**01 March 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [BiGYaN](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/21395/bigyan)
[image: Tree during sunrise - BiGYaN]

*Clicked at 0630 yesterday with a Canon 55-250 on a 1000D. Photoshopped to add more red to the sky. Larger:* http://flic.kr/p/jvWddM

[**21 February 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [namtab](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/35687/namtab)
[image: Galway, Ireland - namtab]

[**14 February 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [eliseo-ocampos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20815/eliseo-ocampos)
[image: Sunset in Montevideo, Uruguay - eliseo-ocampos]

```
Nikon D3100 + Sigma 70-300mm @300mm, f/5.6 @1/2000, ISO 100
```

[**07 February 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [riot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27217/riot)
[image: Dreams of the Sea - riot]

*Although initially this may seem a casual snapshot, in fact it's been an exercise in extreme control - not a single pixel has been left to chance here. An assistant threw gravel at the subject until the ripples on the water and reflections came out exactly how i wanted them - just enough texture to stand out, while maintaining the silent silky feel of the seawater.
Part of a series of photographs shot for a close friend, images of aquatic dissolution, peace in drowning and strength in human creations left to decay by water are intended here.
No crop, cloning of sensor dust and a few distracting specks of dirt on the water, contrast curve adjustment, desaturation with partial blue filter simulated via channel mixer, duotone conversion with a custom sepia curve (using Pantone Warm Grey 7CV), mild dodging and burning, small increase in vibrance, resize, sharpen.
High-res view and more info on DeviantArt:* http://fav.me/d5gk36l

[**30 January 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [jafin](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8550/jafin)
[image: Untitled - jafin]

*5D Mk II @40mm EF17-40 f/4L 25s @ f/11*

[**22 January 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [chaithanya-m](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/13805/chaithanya-m)
[image: Water droplets on leaves - chaithanya-m]

*Taken with Canon Rebel XS (lens was either EF-S 18-55 or EF-S 55-250, don't remember anymore) @ 55mm & f/5.6*

[**15 January 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [jahaziel](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4913/jahaziel)
[image: ¡Vámonos! - jahaziel]

[**08 January 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [damned-truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)
[image: A Cliche - damned-truths]

[**01 January 2017**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [michael nielsen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11455/michael-nielsen)
[image: Death - michael nielsen]

[**25 December 2016**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [russell mcmahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Seeking support - russell mcmahon]

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2016](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5317)
- [Hall of Fame 2015](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043)
- [Hall of Fame 2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659)
- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)