# Are photos from phones allowed in the "photo of the week" contest?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to the photography stack exchange and would like to participate in the Photo of the Week contest. However, I'm also new to photography and only recently got a DSLR camera so I haven't taken many photos with it. Is it okay if I submit some photos I've taken using my phone until I have more taken on my DSLR?

Comment: For many young people, a phone is the only camera they've ever had.  It would be elitist in the extreme to exclude them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They always have been. I see no distinction between a phone, a DSLR, a film camera or even a Box Brownie in this respect.
It's the end result that counts.

I even once won the old 'Image of the week' which was the predecessor of the current competition with a photo taken on an iPhone

I can't direct-link it because at the time the original winner was then deleted from the list & placed in a separate Hall of Fame list.
[Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2017 Archive)](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame-2017-archive) then scroll down to 14 August 2017 if you want to see it.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely, they are allowed. A photo is a photo. While many of us might *personally* be snobs about how we take our own photos with respect to film, dedicated digital SLRs or mirrorless, vs. smartphones, I dare say that **everybody** here respects a good photo, regardless of the imaging source.

Indeed, in many ways, great smartphone photos are even more impressive, considering some of the restrictions they have.

(Counterpoint: recent smartphones with computational photographic technology makes taking great photos easier, in some ways easier than with traditional dedicated cameras. But that's an entirely separate conversation)