# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2018 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of the current year in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

[**24 December 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Toph](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6289/toph)
[image: Soft Sun - Toph]

Exposure correction and sharpening done in Lightroom.

Large Version: https://flic.kr/p/ouDKJH

[**15 December 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Matthieu Moy](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/40449/matthieu-moy)
[image: Jumping Spider - Matthieu Moy]

Focus-stacked from 2 images, [Full resolution](http://mmoy.piwigo.com/picture?/3678/category/15-nature)

[**8 December 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [RGA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24651/rga)
[image: Paddy field - RGA]

[Full Size](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=666747440043261&set=a.666747453376593.1073741828.659549744096364&type=1)

> Camera: Canon 600D Lens: 40mm F/2.8 EF Shutter: 1/4000 Aperture: f/2.8
>   ISO: 100

[**16 November 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [gerlos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20180/gerlos)
[image: Arches of Light - gerlos]

This shot was taken from the porch of a church in Borgo Schirò, an abandoned village in the inland of Sicily, a dark place far away from the artificial lights, and a little closer to the stars.

It shows how the stars in the sky apparently move as time goes by. At the same time, it's an opportunity to think how a once alive place can ruin after people leave it.

> Stack of about 350 shots of 30s, taken from 21.00 to 00.06, developed
>   in Lightroom Classic and merged in Photoshop.
>   Canon EOS 550D camera, Tamron 10-24 mm @10 mm and f/4, 30s, ISO 3200.
>   Before
>   merging the full set of shots I reviewed each image and masked out any
>   track of planes and satellites passing across the frame.

Original: https://flic.kr/p/25s43h2

[**28 October 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Peter Parker](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24813/peter-parker)
[image: Eastern Box Turtle - Peter Parker]

[**14 October 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [SDekov](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/74059/sdekov)
[image: Lumiere London: Festival of Light - SDekov]

[**29 September 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Zosterops lateralis - Russell McMahon]

f/2.8 70mm

[**18 September 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Vaman Kulkarni](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6624/vaman-kulkarni)
[image: Untitled - Vaman Kulkarni]

```
ISO 320 
f5.6
1/800 @ 24mm
```

[**05 September 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Lars Kotthoff](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/16037/lars-kotthoff)
[image: Sunset at Lake Atitlan, Guatemala - Lars Kotthoff]

[Larger version](https://www.flickr.com/photos/larskotthoff/16291017656/in/set-72157648038840424)

[**24 August 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)
[image: Untitled - Russell McMahon]

[**04 August 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Aganju](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/46784/aganju)
[image: The View - Aganju]

Tse'Bii'Ndzisgaii (Monument Valley)

I have been visiting this awe-inspiring place several times, always trying to catch its grandness in a picture. I think this one finally did it - it would have been nice without the Navajo on the horse, but he adds the drama for me.
This is a holy place for the Navajo; all buttes have names, and their gods live atop them. It is a place you have to experience; standing there, turning, and seeing the landscape all around you makes you feel small and insignificant.
*View large [here](https://plus.google.com/+WillPirnasch/posts/NZFSocriuov?pid=6320677049529877618&oid=107261077020442589198)*

[**16 July 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Saaru Lindestøkke](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/saaru-lindest%C3%B8kke)
[image: Beetle - Saaru Lindestøkke]

http://500px.com/photo/23385493

```
Camera: Canon 550D  
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM + close-up filter
Focal Length: 50mm
Aperture: f/4.5
Shutter: 1/60
ISO: 250
```

[**03 July 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Gordon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/471/gordon)
[image: Cherry blossoms - Gordon]

I took the photo in the evening with the camera pointed straight up through the branches. This gave a more intense blue color to the sky. Larger uncropped version: https://flic.kr/p/mmwcdg

[**24 June 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [user126190](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20941)
[image: Time waits for no one - user126190]

Taken at Pykara Falls, Ooty in south India. Technical details : Nikon D5100 with 18-55mm lens
[Bigger version](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1407801942831901&set=a.1386844571594305.1073741826.100008063264430&type=1&theater)

[**14 June 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [lalli](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1438/lalli)
[image: on the way to Rohtang Pass- lalli]

Bigger version [here](https://500px.com/photo/18841741/september-in-the-himalayas-by-lalit-sharma)

[**27 May 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [joey](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2616/joey)
[image: Tower - joey]

Breakwater light in Warnemünde. Full-size image available on [deviantART](https://jo-i.deviantart.com/art/Tower-158839928).

[**20 May 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Slartibartfast](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/8016/slartibartfast)
[image: Untitled - Slartibartfast]

```
Shutter: 1/160
Apperture: f2.8
Camera: Canon 1100D, 
Lens: Sigma 50-150, F2.8 APO EX DC HSM
```

[**13 May 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Alex](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9703/alex)
[image: Far and Away - Alex]

```
Shot from Rauschberg, Ruhpolding
Canon EOS 650D
Lens : Tamron SP 70-200mm F/2.8 Di VC USD
Focal Length : 200mm
Shutter Speed : 1/1250 s
Aperture : f/5.6
ISO/Film : 100
```

[**05 May 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [saaru-lindestøkke](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/saaru-lindest%C3%B8kke)
[image: The Start - saaru-lindestøkke]

```
Camera: Canon 550D  
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
Focal Length: 50mm
Aperture: f/8
Shutter: 1/250s
ISO: 100
Flash: fired behind the subject, straight to the camera
```

[**27 April 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [binaryfunt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/25520/binaryfunt)
[image: Breaking Morning - binaryfunt]

Taken in Richmond Park, London, UK. This is a HDR merge of 3 exposures, using Google HDR Efex Pro 2 and Photoshop.

```
Nikon D7000
Nikon 18.0-135.0 mm kit lens @38 mm
f/22
ISO-400
Taken: 2016-10-22
```

[**13 April 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [tatan](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/44923/tatan)
[image: Water Drop on a flower petal - tatan]

[**02 April 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [filannim](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/62492/filannim)
[image: Boston Public Library - filannim]

```
Camera: Fujifilm X-T20
Lens: Fujinon XF18-55mm f/2.8-4 R LM OIS
Focal length: 18mm
Aperture: f/2.8
Shutter: 1/250 sec
ISO: 1600
Flash: no.
```

[**26 March 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Christoph](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/31313/christoph)
[image: Fishing boats - Christoph]

[**17 March 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Andy M](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28231/skunkness)
[image: Getting up early- Andy M]

Larger version: https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/84667975/m%3D2048/64a3e83c5363540096a2fdcfc0c5e95f

```
    Canon EOS 6D
    Lens : EF100mm f/2.8 Macro USM
    Focal Length : 100mm
```

[**02 March 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Saaru Lindestøkke](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/9161/saaru-lindest%C3%B8kke)
[image: In the midst of battle - Saaru Lindestøkke]

```
Camera: Canon 550D  
Lens: Sigma 18-50mm f/2.8-4.5 DC OS HSM
Focal Length: 50mm
Aperture: f/8
Shutter: 1/250
ISO: 100
Flash: off-camera from far right
```

[**22 February 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Glenn Randers-Pehrson](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/45693/glenn-randers-pehrson)
[image: Cardinal Outside my Basement Window - Glenn Randers-Pehrson]

```
Camera: SONY a300 + 75-300 zoom
Exposure: 1/500, ISO 125, f5.6, 300mm, no flash
Date: 23 February 2015
Note: taken through a double-pane window
LICENSE: CC-BY-SA-3.0 or 4.0
```

[**12 February 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Skunkness](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28231/skunkness)
[image: Nevada Sky- Skunkness]

[**31 January 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Babel](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/26202/babel)
[image: Untitled - Babel]

[**05 January 2018**](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2657) - [Riot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/27217/riot)
[image: Focus - Riot]

Higher-res view and more info on Deviantart: http://fav.me/dan293e

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2017](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5603)
- [Hall of Fame 2016](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5317)
- [Hall of Fame 2015](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043)
- [Hall of Fame 2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659)
- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)