# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2019 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of 2019 in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

**15 November 2019**

**Dubai Marina** - [Muhammed Refaat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/74625/muhammed-refaat)

[image: Dubai Marina - Muhammed Refaat]

Taken with Samsung Note 5 smart phone.
Higher Resolution: https://ibb.co/ezS2bn

**03 November 2019**

**Colourful Soul** - [yohoprashant](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/76729/yohoprashant)

[image: Colourful Soul - yohoprashant]

```
Camera: Nikon D5300
Focal Length: 35.0mm
Aperture: ƒ/4.0
Shutter Speed: 1/2500s
ISO: 500
```

**26 October 2019**

**Shropshire hills** - [Alex](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/67003/alex)

[image: Shropshire hills - Alex]

> Shot on a Samsung NX1000 with 20-50 stock lens
>
> f4.5, 1/250 @ ISO 200

**11 October 2019**

**Rope and block** - [Guffa](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/149/guffa)

[image: Rope and block - Guffa]

Rope and block on a ship in the harbour in Västerås.

Camera: Canon EOS 5D Mark II
Lens: Sigma 50-500 mm f/4-6.3 APO DG
Focal length: 191 mm
Aperture: 7.1
Shutter time: 1/320 s
ISO: 100

Larger: http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=24761

**22 September 2019**

**Western Jackdaw** - [luator](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/38328/luator)

[image: Western Jackdaw - luator]

```
Nikon D5100, 55mm, 1/200s, f5.6, ISO 180
Cropped and converted to B&W with Gimp
```

**07 September 2019**

**Untitled** - [Ian Lelsie](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20973/ian-lelsie)

[image: Untitled - Ian Lelsie]

**29 August 2019**

**The world in the eye of Beau** - [descheleschilder](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/51153/descheleschilder)

[image: The world in the eye of Beau - descheleschilder]

**17 August 2019**

**Dragonfly in flight** - [bbh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28221/bbh)

[image: Dragonfly in flight - bbh]

Dragonfly in full flight. Large size is [here](http://photos.brijeshbhaskaran.com/v/dragonfly/)

**30 July 2019**

**Sunset at Moorea** - [Hagen von Eitzen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28221/hagen-von-eitzen)

[image: Sunset at Moorea - Hagen von Eitzen]

Panasonic DMC-FX01, 1/60s, 8.1mm, ISO 80 (The scenery became even more "firey" a few minutes later, but lacking use of a tripod those pictures are not usable for a competition)

**19 July 2019**

**Frost** - [binaryfunt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/25520/binaryfunt)

[image: Frost - binaryfunt]

Frost glints in the morning sunlight. Taken in a garden in England.

```
Nikon D80
Sigma Macro 50mm F2.8 EX DG
f/4.5
1/320 sec
ISO-320
2014-12-29
```

**12 June 2019**

**Rocky Beach?** - [Dominik](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11838/dominik)

[image: Rocky Beach - Dominik]

Or: chia seeds in fruit and vegetable juice

Larger version with all details in metadata

**03 June 2019**

**Home or prison?** - [user_1177868](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/62492/user-1177868)

[image: Home or prison? - Dean Rather]

```
Camera: Fujifilm X-T20
Lens: Fujinon XF18-55mm f/2.8-4 R LM OIS
Focal length: 18mm (27mm equivalent)
Aperture: f/3.6
Shutter: 1/400 sec
ISO: 200
Flash: no.
```

Original: [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BZiA4OdnFYM/) [PixieSet](http://filannim.pixieset.com/)

**24 May 2019**

**Grounded at Guangzhou** - [Dean Rather](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/16025/dean-rather)

[image: Grounded at Guangzhou - Dean Rather]

Taken while (as the name states) grounded at Guangzhau airport for a few hours during a lightning storm.

I didn't have my tripod with me and these were `0.3s` exposures, so to work around this (and also avoid glare off the window's glass), I took the photos with the camera lens pressed firmly against the glass. -- Work's wonders for omitting glare entirely!

Thankfully I had a ~$15 Lightning Trigger in my camera bag, I still got hundreds of false-positives, but the lightning storm was consistent enough that I got some really nice shots.

I really like the shine on the runway, and the fact that you can even see the reflection of the bolt in the bottom!

Touched up in Lightroom, I'm still pretty new to lightroom so hopefully I didn't over-do anything.

```
Canon EOS 60D EF24-70mm
f/2.8L II USM
ƒ/2.8  24.0mm  0.3s  ISO400
```

Original: https://www.flickr.com/photos/deanrather/14610919696/

**12 May 2019**

**Frozen Droplets** - [bubbles](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/20359/bubbles)

[image: Frozen Droplets - bubbles]

Shot outside my house after an ice storm - where ice was forming on the plastic net shown. Postwork done in GIMP to create more contrast and dynamic range.

- Olympus E-520
- Tamron Adaptall-2 35-135, f/3.5-4.2 (vintage lens from the '80s on an adapter)

[Full-Sized Image](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=39518C0C53436A16!143&authkey=!AKwmz-YCTe3iwVU&v=3&ithint=photo,.png) ([Creative Commons Attribution Non-Com](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/deed.en_US))

**29 April 2019**

**An evening over Paro, Bhutan** - [Ankit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/72041/ankit)

[image: An evening over Paro, Bhutan - Ankit]

**Full Image**: https://500px.com/photo/198203097/an-evening-over-paro-bhutan-by-ankit-rajpoot

**Taken with**: Nikkor 18-55mm f3.5-5.6G VRII lens on a Nikon D5200 in Paro, Bhutan.

**Exposure**: 48mm - ƒ/5.3 - 1/500s - ISO 100

Enhanced in Lightroom.

**Story**: I was lucky to be present at the National Museum of Bhutan in Paro just at the moment when the Sun pulled off this magnificent light trick. That combined with the beauty of the land creates this magical scene that can only be fully experienced by being there. Trust me, I tried my best, but the photo just does not do justice to what my eyes saw there. What you see in this image is the town of Paro as seen from the museum. :)

**22 April 2019**

**The Blue Moon** - [Frank](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/47882/alan-jurgensen)

[image: The Blue Moon - Alan Jurgensen]

Nikon D7200 Manual ISO320 f/22.0 30sec 17.00mm

**13 April 2019**

**Shadows** - [Frank](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20069/frank)

[image: Shadows - Frank]
Canon EOS 60D, Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro IS USM, ISO 100, f/5, 1/400s

Larger version on 500px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OM4B.jpg

**25 March 2019**

**Way back home along the beach** - [kiran](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77651/kiran)

[image: Way back home along the beach - kiran]

Full image: https://500px.com/photo/236004545

**16 March 2019**

**The power of speed flash** - [Maulik V](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24282/maulik-v)

[image: The power of speed flash - Maulik V]

**09 March 2019**

**Sagittarius Arm Above The Trees** - [Prasan Karunarathna](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77487/prasan-karunarathna)

[image: Sagittarius Arm Above The Trees - Prasan Karunarathna]

```
Camera:- Nikon D7000
Lens:- Nikkor 50mm lens
Focus:- Lens focus set to infinity(focus stars)
Shutter :- 20-25 Seconds
F Number:-f/1.8,
ISO:- 800 
Camera Mode:- Manual
Lens Focus:- Manual
Image Format :- Raw
Location :- Sri Lanka / Nikaweratiya
Sky Condition :- I
Use a Tripod and Shutter Release
```

**26 February 2019**

**First Church of Christ, Boston** - [sunset_star](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7895/sunset-star)

[image: First Church of Christ, Boston - sunset_star]

This pic is a reflection of First Church of Christ, the Scientist @ Boston, MA.
It is captured against the reflection pond and rotated 180 degrees. (using a 5 MP phone cam).
The backdrop of nightly colors and the church lights reflecting off the water make it appear dreamy.

**17 February 2019**

**Charco de la laja,Tenerife** - [Jorge Córdoba](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/26180/jorge-c%C3%B3rdoba)

[image: Charco de la laja,Tenerife - Jorge Córdoba]

Took this at sunset with a Haida Big Stopper at sunset (sun behind me). This is a beautiful natural poool formed by the sea filling that natural hole (hence the effect of the silky water going in and out). Beautiful place.

Bigger image [500px](https://500px.com/photo/107285865/charco-de-la-laja-by-c%C3%B3rdoba-sim%C3%B3n)

**08 February 2019**

**Waterfall at Lumsdale** - [Kat](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/48070/kat)

[image: Waterfall at Lumsdale - Kat]

[Original on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/katwesley/20198778433/)

**01 February 2019**

**Chicago Air and Water Show** - [BobT](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/11772/bobt)

[image: Chicago Air and Water Show - BobT]

Nikon D800
340mm (70-200 2.8 with 1.7x extender)
1/4000 f5.6 ISO 400
Full size image: http://rntilden.zenfolio.com/img/s/v-2/p1401799785.jpg

**21 January 2019**

**Horses nibbling each other in a field in Ireland** - [Arseni Mourzenko](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2236/arseni-mourzenko)

[image: Horses nibbling each other in a field in Ireland... - Arseni Mourzenko]

Nikon D7000; AF-S VR Micro-Nikkor 105mm f/2.8G

Shot at f/3.5, ISO 400, 1/1000 s.

**10 January 2019**

**IT'S MINE...** - [Russell McMahon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6263/russell-mcmahon)

[image: IT'S MINE... - Russell McMahon]

Female sparrow telling a male sparrow that she was taking over his bread.
He left. Sigma 70-200mm, f/2.8 + Tamron 2x teleconverter.
More mm needed - birds always need longer lenses :-).

**01 January 2019**

**Eiffel Arch** - [damned truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths)

[image: Eiffel Arch - damned truths]

An arch of the Eiffel Tower.
Larger: http://500px.com/photo/24448559

> Camera: Canon 550D 
> Lens: Canon 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
> Aperture: f/7.1
> Shutter: 1/160 sec
> ISO: 400

## Archives

- [Hall of Fame 2018](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5829)
- [Hall of Fame 2017](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5603)
- [Hall of Fame 2016](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5317)
- [Hall of Fame 2015](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043)
- [Hall of Fame 2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659)
- [Hall of Fame 2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230)
- [Hall of Fame 2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741)
- [Hall of Fame 2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740)
- [Hall of Fame 2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)