# Image of the Week “Hall of Fame” (2020 Archive)

Tags: discussion, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

You may know that https://photo.stackexchange.com/ (this site's parent :) has a "Photo of the week" contest.

Here are all the images featured on the homepage from the beginning of 2020 in reverse chronological order. Historical archives for previous years, see the archives list at the end.

## Hall of Fame

---

#### [1 June, 2020: Lomography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/116991/)

**Audi on turntable, @Paris Auto show 2001** – [Alaska Man](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/50217/alaska-man)

[image: Audi on turntable, @Paris Auto show 2001]

Camera: [Zero Image 4x5 Pinhole camera](http://www.zeroimage.com/Pinhole_Camera_45_2015.html), 4x5 film, Lith Print, Black & White Silver Gelatin, Straight scan of print ( no post color added.)

I do not remember details, I wanna say Ilford HP5 ?  @ 30 seconds to one minute exposure, tripod on the turntable with the car.

---

#### [14 February, 2020: Imperfectly Beautiful](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114433/)

**Razor Wire, Wiesbaden, Feb 4, 2020** – [rackandboneman](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/58185/rackandboneman)

[image: Razor Wire, Wiesbaden, Feb 4, 2020]

Note: Looks like selective color when viewed at a small size. None applied. Just odd, found lighting and camera settings happening to be a little on the weird side from previous night photography....

---

#### [29 January, 2020: Portraits by candlelight](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/114278/)

**Wielder of the Secret Fire** – [LightBender](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/68136/lightbender)

[image: Wielder of the Secret Fire]

```
Camera:   Nikon D700
Lens:     Nikkor 105mm 2.8 Macro
Aperture: f/16
Shutter:  1/5s
ISO:      1600
```

Shot in RAW, converted to B&W in Photoshop with a little dodging for good measure.

---

#### [30 December 2019: 'Tis the season for a fresh start](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/113605)

**Life changing goodness and definitely new beginnings** - [On Break](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/67377/onbreak)

[image: Life changing goodness and definitely new beginnings]

Location: Iceland on a waterfall that I still can't pronounce
Date: December 2017

---

## Hall of Fame Archives

[2019](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7102), [2018](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5829), [2017](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5603), [2016](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5317), [2015](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043), [2014](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4659), [2013](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230), [2012](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3741), [2011](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3740), [2010](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3739)